# Arcs of rotation for angles

Tags: graphics, trigonometry

1. How can I draw trigonometric angles of any radian measure associated with the unit circle, complete with the x-axis and y-axis?
2. How can I draw arcs of rotation inside positive or negative angles?
3. Is there a method for drawing arcs inside angles of more than one rotation?

Here is a link showing what I would like to draw:

http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/coterminal-angles.html

Comment: Holy spirals, Batman!

Comment: Welcome to this site. To continue with your style of writing: **Here is a link showing what I would like you to read: [FAQ]**

Answer (score 8):

Here's something I've used before:

```
rotCircle[angle_, ctr_, base1_, base2_, directives___] :=
 With[{step = 0.05 Sign[angle], spiral = 0.01},
  {directives,
   Arrow[Table[ctr + (1.1 + spiral s) (Cos[s] base1 + Sin[s] base2),
     {s, Append[Range[0, angle, step], angle]}]]}
  ]

Graphics[rotCircle[10., {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1},  Red, Thick], PlotRange -> 1.2]
```

[image: Angle spiral]

The argument `base1` is the starting side and `base2` should be an orthogonal vector pointing in the direction in which the angle increases from `base1`.

---

Just too much fun, or trying to avoid work:

```
Clear[rotCircle];
Module[{spiralPitch = 0.01},
  rotCircle[angle_, ctr_, radius_, directives___] := 
    With[{step = 0.05 Sign[angle]},
      {directives, Arrow[Table[
         ctr + (1.1 + spiralPitch s) (Cos[s] radius + Sin[s] Cross[radius]),
         {s, Append[Range[0, angle, step], angle]}]]}];
  spiral[] := (spiralPitch = 0.01; {});
  spiral[pitch_] := (spiralPitch = pitch; {});
  ];
directedAngle[u_?VectorQ, v_?VectorQ] := Sign[Det[{u, v}]] VectorAngle[u, v];
```

`spiral[pitch]` half works like a directive, except that it is processed in the kernel instead of the front end.  (Also, I got replace `base1`, `base2` by a single `radius`, which is the starting side of the angle.

```
SeedRandom[16];
Module[{pts = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10, 2}], lines}, 
 lines = Normalize /@ Differences@pts;
 Graphics[{Thick, Line[pts], Arrowheads[Small],
   MapThread[
    rotCircle[directedAngle[#1, -#2] +  2 π RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3, 2, 1} -> Range[-2, 2]],
      #3, -0.4 #1, spiral[0.05], Red, Thickness[Medium]] &,
    {Most[lines], Rest[lines], pts[[2 ;; -2]]}]
   }, PlotRange -> All]
 ]
```

[image: Many marked angles]

Answer (score 3):

Does this give you a start?

```
DynamicModule[{p = {1.5, 0}},
 Deploy@LocatorPane[Dynamic[p],
   Dynamic@Graphics[
     {Brown, Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, p/Norm[p]*1.5}],
      Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {Mod[ArcTan @@ p, 2 Pi], 2 Pi}]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> True, 
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], Appearance -> None
   ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I remember that in version 8 there is an undocumented spinny control like this which also takes into account winding. I don't remember what it was called/what package it was in.

Comment: @amr What you mean is probably ``Experimental`AngularSlider[Dynamic[phi]]``

Comment: that's the one! it's such a cute little control

Answer (score 3):

this is the kind of "hack" that I often throw together to illustrate math concepts for my students.   The code is terrible but the result looks okay.  Perhaps there is something here you can use...

[image]

The code...

```
Manipulate[

 If[angle < 0,

  endpt = {Cos[Abs[angle]  Degree], - Sin[Abs[angle] Degree]} + 
    0.1 Abs[angle] Degree {Cos[
       Abs[angle] Degree], -Sin[Abs[angle] Degree]},

  endpt = {Cos[angle Degree], Sin[angle Degree]} + 
    0.1 angle Degree {Cos[angle Degree], Sin[angle Degree]}];
 (*this is the endpoint of the terminal arm*)



 length = EuclideanDistance[{0, 0}, endpt];
 (*this is the length of the terminal arm*)

 Column[{
   If[showQ1, 
    Row[{"Principal angle:  ", 
      ToString[Mod[angle, 360]] <> "\[Degree]"}], " "],
   If[showQ2, 
    Row[{"Angle measure:  ", ToString[angle] <> "\[Degree]"}], ""],
   Graphics[{

     {GrayLevel[0.8], Line[{{- 1.2 length, 0}, {1.2 length, 0}}], 
      Line[{{0, - 1.2 length}, {0, 1.2 length}}]},
     (*draw the axes*)

     {Blue, Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, {length, 0}}]},
     (*initial arm*)

     {Red, Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, endpt}]},
     (*terminal arm*)

     If[angle < 0,
      Arrow[{#[[1]], -#[[2]]} & /@ Table[
         {Cos[i], Sin[i]} + 0.1 i {Cos[i], Sin[i]} , {i, 0, 
          Abs[angle] Degree, 2 \[Pi]/100.}]],

      Arrow[Table[
        {Cos[i], Sin[i]} + 0.1 i {Cos[i], Sin[i]} , {i, 0, 
         angle Degree, 2 \[Pi]/100.}]],
      Arrow[Table[
        {Cos[i], Sin[i]} - 0.1 i {Cos[i], Sin[i]} , {i,  0, 
         angle Degree, 2 \[Pi]/100.}]]]
     (*the spiral and arrow on end*)

     }, ImageSize -> 600]
   }, Alignment -> Center], 
  {{angle, 30}, -1800, 1800, 1},
 Delimiter,
 {{showQ1, False, "Show principal angle value"}, {True, False}},
 {{showQ2, False, "Show angle 1 value"}, {True, False}},
 ControlPlacement -> Left

 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

To give people ideas:

```
angle[a_] := Module[{p}, Show[
    p = PolarPlot[1000 + 10 x, {x, 0, a}, PlotStyle -> Thick],
    Graphics[{Thick, Extract[p, Position[p, _Hue]][[1]],
      Line[{{0, 0}, 1.9 Extract[p, Position[p, _Line]][[1, 1, -1]]}]}]]];

angle[(2 360 + 45) Degree]
```

[image]

Remember to watch for negative angles.

Comment: How would we make this work for negative angles?